# Displaying amount of projects planned and finished per week with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

for some time now I am trying to get some requested visuals to work with the data I have.

**TL,DR:** Visualizing given Projects with a plan- and a finish-week per week in a visual.

## My Problem

I have several tables with project data that should be visualized in a specific way.
I already joined the tables together and now I am trying to get the visualization to work.

This is the joined table for a better understanding (only some columns are shown):

| **ID** | **Plan_Week** | **Finish_Week** | **Category** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 34 | A |
| 2 | 35 | 41 | A |
| 3 | 35 | -1 | B |

*Plan_Week* contains the week in which the project was set to finish.

*Finish_Week* contains the week in which the project has actually been finished.

Now I would like to visualize the data in a bar- and line chart. The x-axis should be the calendar weeks, and the bar should show the amount of projects within the table that were planned for each week.
The line of the chart should visualize how many projects were actually finished each week. The visual should give an overview over the performance at these projects (e.g. more projects finished earlier than planned).

I've already tried several attempts but never got it to work the way I wanted.

Here is an example of what it should look like:

[image: The expected output]

What I mostly get instead is the spike for the project with the ID 2 as finished showing at week 34 when I use *Plan_Week* as the x-axis values:

[image: The actual output I get]

So far what I've done were:

- Creating a new table with Index from 1 to 52 as calendar weeks and calculating how many projects were planned/finished each week.
- Then I also created two separate tables. One containing all planned projects and their weeks and one containing all finished projects and their weeks. I then set a relation from the first table with the calendar weeks to those tables and a relation between the IDs.

Both of these and some other but kind of similar attempts did not work correctly.

The main point of what I want to achieve is to keep this chart interactive in both directions. For example filtering by category:
If I filter by category the visual should show when projects of this category were planned and finished.
On the other hand selecting a specific week in this visual should show how many projects were planned or finished in each category. The problem is that using *Plan_Week* as the x-axis doesnt affect interactions from choosing a point on the line of *Finish_Week*.

I'm fairly new to power BI and really stuck at this point.
Is there a simple way to display both *Plan_Week* and *Finish_Week* in one chart with a continuous x-axis that allows for interaction in both directions? Or is this a little more complicated?

I really appreciate any help and inputs. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple. First you need a table with all the weeks then probably modelling wise you should just have one Project table with a plan week and a finish week (with 2 project tables, you will have to have a separate Category table with relationship to those 2 tables for the Category filter to work)

Then you create a relationship between the Week table and the Plan Week and create another relationship between Week and Finish Week **(at least one of these will have to be inactive)**

Then you create 2 measures, and for each one of them, you tell PowerBI which relationship to activate:

```
PlannedProjects = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Project), USERELATIONSHIP('Week'[WeekID], 'Project'[Plan_Week]))

FinishedProjects = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Project), USERELATIONSHIP('Week'[WeekID], 'Project'[Finish_Week]))
```

Then used one measure as the bar and another one as the line.

Note: This will return blanks for weeks with no data, if you want to have 0s instead just add `+ 0` to the end each of the measure formulae, to force them to return a number.